# Want to constrain size of content within parent column's size [twitter bootstrap]

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-carousel

the main issue that I am having is that the contents within the bootstrap columns are not matching to fit the size of their respective columns.

This is the layout that I would like
[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrZQF.jpg)

This page is broken into two separate columns

- left column (c-carousel column): bootstrap image carousel
- right column (gm-group members column): name and picture of each member of the group

  - right column is broken down into 1 title row and 10 additional rows containing two columns 
    each

Each main column is set to "max-height: 100%;max-width: 100%;", and these do both conform to the maximum height and maximum width dimensions of the main row. But their respective contents (carousel and group members columns) do not, and that is where the problem is. The c column's content or the gm column's content will extend further than the height of the other column when the page is viewed on larger or smaller screens, and that creates blank areas, like the yellow space below. I have changed it so that the gm column's content fits within the column's dimensions, but there is still overflow, which I have set to hidden, but this is not optimal because you have to scroll to view the last member.

I'd like to have it so that the carousel crops into the images as necessary to fit within the constraints of its columns and the group members column's content constrains to fit the dimensions of the column without having to scroll through the members, but I am not sure how to do that and I have been trying for three days. Thank you in advance for any help.

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p92ZR.png)

**Here is the related code:**

```
        img.headshots{
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        #top{
            background-color: #467095;
            text-align: center;
            font-family:Impact, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.8em;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }
        #mobilenamediv{
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #fullnamediv{
            display: none;
        }
        #name{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.3rem;
            color: white;
            background-color: #467095;
            align-items: stretch;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding-top: 4.4%;
            padding-bottom: 3%;
            padding-left: 3%;
            /* padding-bottom: 5%;  */
            justify-content: space-between;
            max-height: auto;
        }
        #name:hover{
            background-color: white;
            color: #467095;
        }
        .headshots{

            vertical-align: middle;
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
        }
        #imageText{
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 20px;
            right: 20px;
            background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
            color: white;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            font-size: 3rem;
        }

        #IMTextTitle{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 2.5rem;
        }

        #IMText{
            font-weight: 500;
            font-size: 1.8rem;
        }

        @media (min-width:992px){
            #fullnamediv{
                display: block;
            }
            #mobilenamediv{
                display: none;
            }
            #name{
                height: 10%;
            } 
        }

        @media (max-width:575px){
            #IMTextTitle{
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 1.5rem;
            }

            #IMText{
                font-weight: 500;
                font-size: 1.0rem;
            }

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <?php include 'navigation.php';?>
    </div>

    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-xs-12" style="padding-right: 0px;max-width: 100%; max-height:100%;background-color: yellow;">
                <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" >
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img src="images/REU_photos/adult-swim2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                        <!-- <img class="d-block w-100" style="object-fit: cover;" src="images/REU_photos/adult-swim2.jpg" alt="First slide"> -->
                        <div id="imageText">
                            <div id="IMTextTitle">Industry Tour:</div>
                            <div id="IMText">Turner Studios and Adult Swim Studios</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="images/REU_photos/Booker_Edwards_workshop.JPG" alt="Second slide">
                        <div id="imageText">
                            <div id="IMTextTitle" >Research Talk:</div>
                            <div id="IMText" >Recording Studio Basics and Signal Flow</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="images/REU_photos/Turner_Studios_tour2.JPG" alt="Second slide">
                        <div id="imageText">
                            <div id="IMTextTitle">Industry Tour:</div>
                            <div id="IMTextTitle">Turner Studios and Adult Swim Studios</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="images/REU_photos/group1.JPG" alt="Third slide">
                        <div id="imageText">
                            <div id="IMTextTitle">2019 REU Researchers</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="images/REU_photos/vr-cave.JPG" alt="Third slide">
                        <div id="imageText">
                            <div id="IMTextTitle">GSU VR Cave</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3" id="fullnamediv" style="max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;overflow:auto;">
            <div id="top">
                    <center><font color="white"><b>Researchers : 2019</b></font></center>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img src="images/AbuNadim.JPG" class="headshots" alt="AbuNadim">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9" id="text">
                            Abu Nadim Kabir
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img src="images/Evelyn.jpg" class="headshots" alt="Evelyn">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9" id="text">
                            Evelyn Bailey
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img src="images/Derek.jpg" class="headshots" alt="Derek">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9" id="text">
                            Derek Roberts
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img src="images/Diane.jpg" class="headshots" alt="Diane">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9" id="text">
                            Diane Nguyen
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img src="images/Joseph1.jpg" class="headshots" alt="Joseph">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9" id="text">
                            Joseph Hamlet
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img src="images/Lillian.jpg" class="headshots" alt="Lillian">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9" id="text">
                            Lillian Le
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img src="images/Michael.jpg" class="headshots" alt="Michael">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9" id="text">
                            Michael Tinglof
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3" style="padding-top: 3%;">
                        <img src="images/Raquel.jpg" class="headshots" alt="Raquel">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9" id="text">
                            Raquel Zempoalteca Roman
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img src="images/Richard.jpg" class="headshots" alt="Richard">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9" id="text">
                            Richard Wiedenroth
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <img src="images/Trenton.jpg" class="headshots" alt="Trenton">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9" id="text">
                            Trenton Plager
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

p.s. please don't judge my code, I know there are a few duplicate and unused sections, but I haven't optimized yet. Thanks again for all of the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code hope will help you

```css
 body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }

 .carousel-inner{
  border-bottom: 40px solid yellow;
 }
 .item{
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
 }
 .user-detail{
  display: inline-block;
 }
 .user-detail p{
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
 }
 img.headshots{
  border-radius: 50%;
 }
 #mobilenamediv{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
 }
 #fullnamediv{
  height: 100vh;
 }
 .banner-sec .col-lg-9, .banner-sec .col-lg-3{
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
 }
 .top{
  font-family:Impact, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.8em;
 }
 #name{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(100vh / 11);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: #467095;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 }
 #name:hover{
  background-color: white;
  color: #467095;
 }
 .headshots{

  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
 }
 #imageText{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 3rem;
 }

 #IMTextTitle{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 #IMText{
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="banner-sec">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-9 col-xs-12">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
     <div class="carousel-inner" >
      <div class="item  active">
       <img src="images/dish.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
       <div class="carousel-caption" id="imageText">
        <div id="IMTextTitle">Industry Tour:</div>
        <div id="IMText">Turner Studios and Adult Swim Studios</div>
       </div>
      </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="images/1.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
      <div id="imageText">
       <div id="IMTextTitle" >Research Talk:</div>
       <div id="IMText" >Recording Studio Basics and Signal Flow</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="images/3.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      <div id="imageText">
       <div id="IMTextTitle">Industry Tour:</div>
       <div id="IMTextTitle">Turner Studios and Adult Swim Studios</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="images/2.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
      <div id="imageText">
       <div id="IMTextTitle">2019 REU Researchers</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block w-100 h-100" src="images/dish.png" alt="Third slide">
      <div id="imageText">
       <div id="IMTextTitle">GSU VR Cave</div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3" id="fullnamediv">
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
    <div class="top text-center">Researchers : 2019</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
    <div class="user-detail">
     <img src="images/download.jpg" class="headshots" alt="AbuNadim">
     <p>Abu Nadim Kabir</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
    <div class="user-detail">
     <img src="images/download.jpg" class="headshots" alt="AbuNadim">
     <p>lyn Bailey</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
    <div class="user-detail">
     <img src="images/download.jpg" class="headshots" alt="AbuNadim">
     <p>Derek Roberts</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
    <div class="user-detail">
     <img src="images/download.jpg" class="headshots" alt="AbuNadim">
     <p>Derek Roberts</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
    <div class="user-detail">
     <img src="images/download.jpg" class="headshots" alt="AbuNadim">
     <p>Derek Roberts</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
    <div class="user-detail">
     <img src="images/download.jpg" class="headshots" alt="AbuNadim">
     <p>Derek Roberts</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
    <div class="user-detail">
     <img src="images/download.jpg" class="headshots" alt="AbuNadim">
     <p>Derek Roberts</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
    <div class="user-detail">
     <img src="images/download.jpg" class="headshots" alt="AbuNadim">
     <p>Raquel Zempoalteca Roman</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
    <div class="user-detail">
     <img src="images/download.jpg" class="headshots" alt="AbuNadim">
     <p>Richard Wiedenroth</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="name">
    <div class="user-detail">
     <img src="images/download.jpg" class="headshots" alt="AbuNadim">
     <p>Trenton Plager</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

:

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it really helped out a lot :)